# Replace multiple strings in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have to remove a specific set of words from a string.
E.g. following words needs to removed (ooh,aah and etc) from an `employee_description`.
Below query I have tried:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(emp_desc, 'aah', ''), 'ooh', '')
from TEST_Table;
```

It's working fine.

But is there any other Best Way to do this.

Comment: And by "best way" you meant what exactly? Is this query slow? Or there are other reasons that make you search for a "best way".

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: I guess OP doesn't want to call `replace` on each pattern..

Comment: @PrakashBaskaran, define "best". What you are doing is fine. What is the problem, is the query slower? Also, you might want to trim extra spaces in the output.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
select regexp_replace(emp_desc, 'aah|ooh', '') from TEST_Table;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50dce/2)

Comment: Remember, `REGEXP_REPLACE` is **not faster** than `REPLACE`. It would consume more CPU.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there any other Best Way to do this.

Define "best". I think your query is fine, unless you are having any performance issues. By the way, `REGEXP_REPLACE` would be a costlier operation, and would be slower than traditional `REPLACE`. Regular expressions are **CPU intensive operations**, though with newer releases the difference in performance is narrowing down, however, they are still slower than traditional functions.

By the way, you might want to **TRIM** the extra space after replacing the string.

```
SQL> column str format a5
SQL> WITH DATA(emp_desc) AS(
  2  SELECT 'scott aah' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'allen ooh' FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(emp_desc,'aah'),'ooh')) str FROM DATA;

STR
-----
scott
allen

SQL>
```

Comment: @PrakashBaskaran You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others. Also, please reply to the comments above on your question.